# Remove application with status "Required" on real BlackBerry device

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am unable to debug my application using Eclipse > Run on device and so I am trying to load the app onto the device with an ALX file using the "Blackberry Desktop Software." However, I am unable to remove it using the device **or** the desktop software because the status is "Required." (see sample picture below)

Where is this status set and how can I remove it so I can actually run my application?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't posted your .alx file (yet), but my guess would be that somehow this got put into it:

```xml
<required>true</required>
```

Just remove that from the file.

[Source: blackberry.com](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/7693/Elements_and_attributes_for_alx_files_513046_11.jsp):

> The required element lets you force an application to load. The
>   application loader tool of the BlackBerry Desktop Manager selects the
>   BlackBerry device application for installation, and the BlackBerry
>   device user cannot change this selection. Add the following line:
>   true.
>
> Only corporate system administrators should use the required tag. This
>   tag should not be used by third-party software vendors.

**Update:** if the mistake has already been made, installing the app with `<required>true</required>` in the .alx file, then you can fix this by manually uninstalling the app at the (desktop) command line.  For example, on a Windows system, the command might be:

```
>"C:\eclipse\indigo\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\bin\JavaLoader.exe" erase -f HelloBlackBerry

RIM Wireless Handheld Java Loader
Copyright 2001-2009 Research In Motion Limited
Connected
Erasing HelloBlackBerry                Done
Disconnected
```

Make sure to use the `-f` flag!  After that, the app will be gone.  You can then reinstall it, making sure not to mark it as `<required>`.  I incremented the version number in the alx file, after removing the `required` tag, although I don't know that this is necessary.

Comment: What if an older version of the application is already on the device?

Comment: Do you mean, "what if somebody already made this mistake, and I now need to update the app"?

Comment: You nailed it, precisely.

Comment: Trying now - thanks very much, I didn't want to reset the whole device

Comment: Beautiful, that worked. I had to use the `-u` flag to tell it to use USB.

Comment: Good show.  Yeah, I didn't have to use `-u`, but I know that sometimes, I do.  It might be that if you have Eclipse open, or a simulator running, it might need to be told that you want the device (USB), and not the simulator.  Maybe if Eclipse and simulator are closed, `-u` isn't required.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to reset the BlackBerry, which what I was trying to accomplish.

First, remove the IT policies on the BlackBerry:

```
loader.exe /resettofactory
```

- How to reset the BlackBerry smartphone to factory defaults:

  http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/KB18998

Second, perform a security wipe including third-party applications.

- How to delete all data and applications from the BlackBerry smartphone using the Security Wipe option:

  http://www.blackberry.com/btsc/KB14058